# How to write Jasmine unit tests for this block of code

Tags: javascript, jasmine, marionette

I need help understanding how to design test for this piece of code:

```
  onSuccessHandler(response) {
    if (response && this.cartModel.hasData(response)) {
      const data = this.cartModel.parse(response);
      this.cartModel.set(data);
      cartChannel.request('render:cart');
    }
  }
```

I tried this, to see if request was called on cart channel, it seems to be passing, but code coverage still shows the block above is not covered :).

```
 describe('Cart suite', () => {
let view;
const cartChannel = Radio.channel('cart');
      beforeEach(() => {
        view = new CartWidgetView({
          model: new Model(fixturesObject),
          cartModel,
        });
        view.render();
      });

it('should request cart if response has data', () => {
        //spyOn Channel in beforeEach method
        view.cartModel = {
          hasData: () => true,
          parse: () => true,
          set: (data) => {
            view.data = data;
          },
        };
        view.onButtonClick();
        view.render();
        const response = {};
        cartChannel.trigger('render:cart', cartModel);
        view.onSuccessHandler(response);
        expect(cartChannel.request).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(cartChannel.request).toHaveBeenCalledWith('get:model');
      });
 });
```

I'm new to TDD using Jasmine with MarionetteJS. The goal is to get it covered by test coverage.

Comment: You should show us more of the test, what `describe` block is this `it` block under? Also, you might also want to check if the 'data' has been set correctly by the cartModel. So `expect(view.data).to.eq(data);` or something. I haven't used jasmine that much, does it have 'context'? like `context('when the response doesn't have data', () => { it('should...', () => {}})` - I guess you can nest multiple `describe` blocks and use those as the context

Comment: Added a describe method, not much going on there, just the fixtures loaded, the cartChannel initialization mostly.